# Hive table, order by is returning the column names as well

Tags: hive, hiveql

I created a hive table and then imported the data from the csv file.
when i am doing the order by query on salary, it gives me the right output but in the end it lists column names.

Please see attached screenshot.

Any help would be much appreciated :)

[![Creating Hive table
][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbzKt.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbzKt.png)

[image: We can see column names are shown (id, name, salary, department, location,]

[image: Csv file]

Select* from emp_tb screenshot does not give column names
[image: select * from emp_tb;]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can skip header from being selected using

`tblproperties("skip.header.line.count"="1")`  Add this at the end of your table DDL.

Or you can alter existing table:

```
ALTER TABLE emp_tb SET TBLPROPERTIES ("skip.header.line.count"="1");
```

If you want header to be displayed in Hive CLI, set this property in Hive:

```
set hive.cli.print.header=true;
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. I have one more question. When i do select * from emp_tb;
it does not show the column names, what am i doing wrong here?
I just added the screenshot for this in the original post

Comment: Sorry I am new to hive and learning it, can you please tell me how to set this property?

set hive.cli.print.header=true;

Comment: @user2977218 paste it before query.

Answer (score 0):

You can skip header from being selected using

tblproperties("skip.header.line.count"="1") Add this at the end of your table DDL.

Or you can alter existing table:

ALTER TABLE emp_tb SET TBLPROPERTIES ("skip.header.line.count"="1");
If you want header to be displayed in Hive CLI, set this property in Hive:

set hive.cli.print.header=true;